# Is the function $ f$ differentiable at every point $x$?

Tags: calculus

Let $ f $ be the function defined as follows: $ f(0) = 1$ and  $f(x)= \frac{\sin x}{x} $ if  $x \neq 0 $. Show that $ f $ is differentiable at every point $x $  ( at $ 0 $ also! ) and evaluate its derivative.

At first I took $f(x)= \frac{\sin x}{x} $ function and wrote that it is continuous function because

$ \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} $  and $ \lim_{x\to 0^{-}}$ both equals to  one.

Now if we discus the graph of  $ f(x) $  when $ x \in ( - \infty ; \infty ) $ we will see that the graph is continuous so the function is differentiable.

$$ 
\begin{cases} f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ f(x) = 1 & x = 0  \end{cases}$$

$$ 
\begin{cases} f^{'}(x) = \frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^{2}}  \\ f^{'}(x) = ?  \end{cases}$$
is the derivative of $ f(x) $ when $ x = 0 $  $ \rightarrow $ $ f^{'}(x) = 0 $ ?

Comment: Well il you check the limit of $f^{\prime}(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, you get your answer $0$

Comment: yes, but can you give me a hint how to prove it?

Comment: I wrote a quick answer below

Comment: Your argument is wrong. Continuous does not imply differentiable !

Comment: Where did I imply differentiability from continuity?

Comment: "the graph is continuous so the function is differentiable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it exists ,
$$f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x+h)}{x+h}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-(x+h)}{h(x+h)}$$
and in $x=0$ this is
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)-h}{h^2}=\frac{\not h-\frac{h^3}{3!}+o(h^4)-\not h}{h^2}=-\frac{h}{6}+o(h^2)\rightarrow 0\mbox.$$
This is how i would do it, hope there are no mistakes tho.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital, twice,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\cos(h)-1}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin(h)}{2}=0.$$

For nonzero angles, you can use formal differentiation and all expressions are defined.